# Objective-C: Getting the highest enum type from a collection

Tags: objective-c, enums

If I have the following enum type:

```
   typedef enum {Type1=0, Type2, Type3} EnumType;
```

And the following code (which will work fine if converted to Java):

```
   NSArray *allTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Type1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:Type2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:Type3], nil];

   EnumType aType = -1;

   NSLog(@"aType is %d", aType); // I expect -1

   // Trying to assign the highest type in the array to aType
   for (NSNumber *typeNum in allTypes) {
      EnumType type = [typeNum intValue];
      NSLog(@"type is: %d", type);
      if (type > aType) {
         aType = type;
      }
   }
   NSLog(@"aType is %d", aType); // I expect 2
```

The resulted logs are:

```
TestEnums[11461:b303] aType is: -1
TestEnums[11461:b303] type  is: 0
TestEnums[11461:b303] type  is: 1
TestEnums[11461:b303] type  is: 2
TestEnums[11461:b303] aType is: -1
```

And when I inspect the value of aType using a breakpoint, I see:

```
aType   = (EnumType) 4294967295
```

Which is [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations#Size) the maximum unsigned long int value for 32-bit systems.

- Does this mean that I cannot assign a value to enum types that is not
  in the valid range of the type's values?
- Why is the value of the log (-1) differ from the real value
  (4294967295)? Does it have something to do with the specifier (%d)?
- How can I achieve want I'm trying to do here without adding a new
  type to represent an invalid value? Note that the collection may
  sometimes be empty, this is why I'm using -1 at the beginning to indicate that there is no type if the collection was empty.

Note: I'm new to Objective-C/ANSI-C.

Thanks,
Mota

**EDIT:**

Here is something weird I've found. If I change the condition inside the loop to:

```
if (type > aType || aType == -1)
```

I get the following logs:

```
TestEnums[1980:b303] aType is -1
TestEnums[1980:b303] type is: 0
TestEnums[1980:b303] type is: 1
TestEnums[1980:b303] type is: 2
TestEnums[1980:b303] aType is 2
```

Which is exactly what I'm looking for! The weird part is how's (aType == -1) true, while (Type1 > -1), (Type2 > -1) and (Type3 > -1) are not?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like `EnumType` is defined to be an `unsigned` type. When you assign it to `-1`, this value actually rolls back to the highest possible value for an unsigned 32-bit integer (as you found). So, by starting the value at `-1`, you are ensuring that **no other value that you compare it to could possibly be higher**, because it is assigned to the maximum value for the data type (`4294967295`).

I'd suggest just starting the counter at `0` instead, as it is the lowest possible value for an `EnumType`.

```
EnumType aType = 0;
```

If you want to check to see if *any* value was chosen, you can check the `count` of the collection to see if there are any values first.

Comment: Thanks @mopsled for your time. The problem with your suggestion is that if the collection was empty, I will end up with aType == 0, which is the same value as Type1's, so the result will be misleading. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Check `[allTypes count]` first. If this is zero, then you won't find any value. Otherwise (if `allTypes` has one or more elements), then your code is all set to find the maximum value.

Comment: This isn't really the answer to what was wrong with the original code, but just a tip: If you want the maximum value from an array, you can just use `[array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"]`.

Comment: @mopsled, Thank you very much. I was hoping to find a simpler way to achieve this because I'm using this code lots of times with lots of enum types. I'll wait two more days to see whether a simpler way exists. And then I will choose an answer. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @Chuck, Awesome tip Chuck! Thank you very much, you just made my day.